# asp.net mvc Razor View loop over <p>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor View.

In my model I got a string property, which can contain several `<p>` tags.

```
public string Description { get; set; }
```

I now want to loop over my `<p>` in the Razor view, somehow like this and put them into a new `div` with a class name:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Count all <p>; i++)
{
   <div class="newParagraph">@Html.Raw(@Model.Description part <p> to </p> )</div>
}
```

My question is now, is it possible to loop over my `<p>` in the string property and put each paragraph into it's own `div`?

Which approach could you suggest to achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack to parse it.

Comment: .Replace("<p>", "<div>").Replace("</p>", "</div>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do

```
@Html.Raw(@Model.Description.Replace("<p>", "<div class=\"newParagraph\">").Replace("</p>", "</div>"));
```